The file 'flutter.yaml' from the 'flutter_lints' package can't be found when analyzing the project due to an issue in 'analysis_options.yaml'
I encountered an issue where the 'flutter.yaml' file from the 'flutter_lints' package could not be found when analyzing my project. This problem occurred when I tried to run a code analysis on my Flutter project. The error message pointed to the 'analysis_options.yaml' file, indicating that it could not locate the necessary 'flutter.yaml' file. I need help resolving this issue to proceed with my project analysis.
I checked the 'analysis_options.yaml' file to ensure the path to 'flutter.yaml' was correct. I also tried reinstalling the 'flutter_lints' package to make sure it was properly included in my project. Despite these efforts, the error persisted. I expected the analysis to run without issues, but it failed because it couldn't find the 'flutter.yaml' file. I need guidance on how to correctly reference this file or troubleshoot the issue further.

Could you amend your post to show under what section you added flutter_lints in your pubspec.yaml file?
